# EF Core is not loading overridden property values with initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have some trouble understanding what happens here and how I can avoid this in the future:
Using EF Core 5.0 with ABP and an Sqlite in memory database.

I have an abstract base entity `Base` and deriving entities, like `A` and `B`:

```
public abstract class Base : Entity<Guid>
{
    public virtual string Category { get; set; }
    public virtual string SubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override string Category { get; set; } = "CategoryA";
    public override string SubCategory { get; set; } = "Other";
}

public class B : Base
{
}
```

When I now create an instance of `A` and set the property `Model` to some different value, I only see the initialized value after loading the entity again.
So a test like this one would fail with the actual result being `string.Empty`/"".

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var a = new A
    {
        SubCategory = "Sub A"
    };
    var inserted = AppService.Insert(a);

    // Act
    var reloadedA = AppService.Get(inserted.Id);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(a.SubCategory, reloadedA.SubCategory);
}
```

And the ApplicationService `AppService` is using ABP's repository pattern (which is just to encapsulate the DbSet in a way) to do the insert and get:

```
public class AppService : ApplicationService
{
    public IRepository<A, Guid> Repo { get; }

    public AppService(IRepository<A, Guid> repository) => Repo = repository;
    
    public Entity<Guid> Insert(A entity)
    {
       var insertedEntity = Repo.Insert(entity);
       CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
       return insertedEntity;
    }

    public Entity<Guid> Get(Guid id)
    {
       return Repo.Get(id);
    }
}
```

Same test for entity `B` works.

It is annoying when I want to seed multiple instances of `A` to a database but also like to keep the default value `"Other"` for the case I want to instantiate an object of type `A` at runtime.

What is the best way to go here? Not using initializers and create instances programmatically using a factory instead?
Just wondering if there is way be configuring EF Core to make this work like "database data first"?

Comment: I can not see how you create reloadedA . Pls post it too

Comment: For class A implement default constructor with assignment default values. Then you don't need overrides props.

Comment: @Serge, I added the saving and loading logic according to how it's to be used in a simple way with ABP. But I think that's just default behavior.

Comment: Thanks @benuto, using a default constructor for initializing the values is a quite good idea in the end. :D

Comment: @Phija - I'm glad